# Lissajous Curve dense in a Volume

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, recreational-mathematics

The Lissajous-type curve $\left(\sin(\omega_1 t), \sin(\omega_2 t)\right)$, with $t \in \mathrm{R}$, is dense in a certain region of the plane.

This can be seen for instance from excellent answers to a previous question of mine: [Curve dense inside the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748927/curve-dense-inside-the-unit-circle).

Consider now the curve $\left(\sin(\omega_1 t), \sin(\omega_2 t), \sin(\omega_3 t)\right)$ with $t \in \mathrm{R}$, and assume that the three frequencies are incommensurable.

Is this curve dense in some 3-dimensional region of finite volume? Or is it also dense just inside a 2-dimensional surface?

$\textbf{ADDED QUESTION}$:

And how about a similar curve in four dimensions (four sines with incommensurate frequencies); would it be dense in a 4-dimensional region of space? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"fill"... Since the curve is continuously differentiable its image must have enmpty interior. Regarding whether the image can be dense in a non-empty open set, (pairwise) incommensurable is not quite the right condition. In fact

> > The image is dense in $[-1,1]^3$ if and only if $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, $\omega_3$ are rationally independent.

Meaning that $r_1\omega_1+r_2\omega_2+r_3\omega_3=0$,  $r_j$ rational  implies $r_1=r_2=r_3=0$.

If the $\omega_j$ are not rationally independent there exist integers $n_j$ with $\sum n_j\omega_j=0$ and not all $n_j$ vanish. I think it's clear that this implies the curve is not dense, although I haven't written a formal proof.

Define $$\gamma(t)=(e^{i\omega_1t},e^{i\omega_2t},e^{i\omega_3t}).$$
Say $\Bbb T=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$. It *is* clear that if the $\omega_j$ are rationally dependent then $\gamma$ is not dense in $\Bbb T^3$.

On the other hand, if the $\omega_j$ are rationally independent then a standard elegant argument using Fourier series shows that $\gamma$ is dense in $\Bbb T^3$ (hence your curve is dense in $[-1,1]^3$). Sketch:

Suppose the $\omega_j$ are rationaly independent. Consider the equation $$\left(\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\right)^3f(e^{it_1},e^{it_2},e^{it_3})\,dt_1dt_2dt_3=\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_0^Tf(\gamma(t))\,dt,\tag{*}$$which may or may not hold for a given $f\in C(\Bbb T^3)$. Show that $(*)$ holds if $f$ is a character, that is $$f(e^{it_1},e^{it_2},e^{it_3})=e^{i(n_1t_1+n_2t_2+n_3t_3)}$$for some integers $n_j$. (Hint: If $n_1=n_2=n_3=0$ both sides equal $1$; if not, the fact that $\sum n_j\omega_j\ne0$ shows that both sides equal $0$.)

Hence $(*)$ holds if $f$ is a trigonometric polynomial (a linear combination of characters). Since the trigonometric polynomials are dense in $C(\Bbb T^3)$ it follows that $(*)$ holds for every $f\in C(\Bbb T^3)$, hence $\gamma$ must be dense in $\Bbb T^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\sqrt2$, $b=\sqrt3$, $c=\sqrt5$.

```
   ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[a t],Sin[b t],Sin[c t]},{t,-100,100}]
```

[image]

The curve will not fill a surface or a volume. No differentiable curve can do that.

### Answer to the edited question

There are cases where the image is not dense. The following follows this [post in Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/04/24/a-tale-of-three-cosines-an-experimental-mathematics-adventure/).

Let $\phi$ be the golden ratio. Then the image of the curve $(\sin t,\sin(\phi\,t),\sin(\phi^2\,t))$ is contained in the surface
$$
(2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)^2 = 4 (1 - x^2) (1 - y^2) (1 - z^2).
$$

Comment: Thank you!, but posting the image is  not enough to prove that a curve is dense in a volume. It looks dense, but a proof is a different thing!

Comment: When I wrote the answer, there was no mention to density, unless my memory fails.

Comment: You are right, I didn't word it properly. And your figure is helpful because it suggests the denseness.

Comment: I'm actually particularly interested in the case where the frequencies are square roots of prime numbers. Numerically it seems that the image is dense in a volume.

Comment: I suspect that the image will be dense "for almost all" choices.

Comment: Yes. The reasons are explained in the linked post: the algebraic relation $1+\phi=\phi^2$ and trigonometric identities.

Comment: Would you say the same is true in higher dimensions? For instance, four cosines with incommensurate frequencies yielding denseness in a 4d volume?

Comment: @Jennifer Incommensurable is not the right condition. If $\phi$ is the golden ratio then $1$, $\phi$ and $\phi^2$ _are_ (pairwise) incommensurable. See my answer.